# How do I open browser in specific "profile" using BATCH script in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, microsoft-edge

Here is the shell script I have used to open the specific URL

```
   start microsoft-edge: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

However, I have multiple `Profiles` defined in `Edge` browser.

How do I open a browser based on the `Profile` name ? How do I pass `Profile` name or path in script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `--profile-directory="Profile name"` to open Edge with specific profile.

The sample code for batch file is like this:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask --profile-directory="Profile 1"
```

Note: please edit the Edge path and profile name to your owns.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on linux so I can't test it but you can test with one of those arguments :

`--user-data-dir="C:\ChromeBrowser_profiles\Profile_edge"`

or

`--profile-directory="Profile 4"`

Comment: Or just `--login-profile=USERNAME`

Comment: It's for windows OS.

Comment: Interesting...  even though I renamed all my profiles "Personal", "Work", "Gaming"...  
--profile-directory="Personal" launches and creates a new blank profile "Profile 4".  
--profile-directory="Profile 1" launches and opens my "Personal" profile.

So the profile rename does not seem to apply to this command-line option.  Not great but I'll take it.